# CSS - Shrink a background image to fit a div

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS for a two-button voting system I am developing:

```
.upvote, .downvote {
    display: inline-block;

    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 0;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 25px auto;

    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.upvote {
    background: url('./parts/icons/upvote.png');
}
.downvote {
    background: url('./parts/icons/downvote.png');
}
```

Also:

```
<div class="upvote"></div>
<div class="downvote"></div>
```

The divs are set to a width and height of 25px, but the images upvote.png and downvote.png are much larger than that (128x128). I need to have the images shrink to 25x25 to fit the divs with CSS, but so far nothing is visible within the divs.

If anyone can help me with this it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: why there is two `background-size` ?

Comment: Oops.. Removed the second one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

:)

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work... Inspect element shows it as crossed out.

Comment: than you have to add `!important` to it @Richie378

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-image: url(your file location here);
background-size:cover; /*(will only work with css3)*/
```